# Kafka, timeout waiting for a node assignment?

Tags: macos, apache-kafka

Following the getting started guide, I get the following error:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
> (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

What I have done is start the two servers with the commands:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

and

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

and then execute the following command, where I'm getting the error:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I'm running on macOS Mojave

When starting the Kafka server, I obtain this log:

```
[2019-12-08 17:50:53,929] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10002516aaf0000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-12-08 17:50:53,957] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10002516aaf0000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0x7 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-12-08 17:50:53,977] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10002516aaf0000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0xa txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-12-08 17:50:54,282] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10002516aaf0000 type:create cxid:0x15 zxid:0x15 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/cluster Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /cluster (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-12-08 17:50:55,247] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10002516aaf0000 type:multi cxid:0x37 zxid:0x1c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Comment: Are you sure that both Zookeeper and Kafka started? Are there errors in the output? Which version did you download?

Comment: @cricket_007 i updated with the log of the kafka server start

Comment: And Zookeeper logs? Did you edit any settings at all?

Comment: in zookeeper logs there is no trace of error, no i don't edit any setting

Comment: I'm not sure, then. I know I've started Kafka through brew and docker. Not sure I've tried just downloading the package on Mac

Answer (score 3):

Apache Kafka comes with an incomplete configuration.

What worked for me is changing server.properties enabling the listeners parameter.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Please note that the example disabled line misses the hostname (*listeners=://localhost:9092*)