# "Kafka Timed out waiting for a node assignment." on MSK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, serverless

Specs:

- The serverless Amazon MSK that's in preview.
- t2.xlarge EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2
- Installed Kafka from https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/3.0.0/kafka_2.13-3.0.0.tgz
- openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode,
  sharing)
- Gradle 7.3.3
- https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth, successfully built.

I also tried adding IAM authentication information, as recommended by the [Amazon MSK Library for AWS Identity and Access Management](https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth). It says to add the following in config/client.properties:

```
# Sets up TLS for encryption and SASL for authN.
security.protocol = SASL_SSL

# Identifies the SASL mechanism to use.
sasl.mechanism = AWS_MSK_IAM

# Binds SASL client implementation.
# sasl.jaas.config = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;

# Encapsulates constructing a SigV4 signature based on extracted credentials.
# The SASL client bound by "sasl.jaas.config" invokes this class.
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler

# Binds SASL client implementation. Uses the specified profile name to look for credentials.
sasl.jaas.config = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required awsProfileName="kafka-client";
```

And `kafka-client` is the IAM role attached to the EC2 instance as an instance profile.

**Networking**: I used VPC Reachability Analyzer to confirm that the security groups are configured correctly and the EC2 instance I'm using as a Producer can reach the serverless MSK cluster.

**What I'm trying to do**: create a topic.

**How I'm trying**: `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server boot-zclcyva3.c2.kafka-serverless.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:9098`
Result:

```
Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
[2022-01-17 01:46:59,753] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

**I'm also trying**: with the plaintext port of 9092. ([9098 is the IAM-authentication port in MSK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/port-info.html), and serverless MSK uses IAM authentication by default.)

All the other posts I found on SO about this node assignment error didn't include MSK. I tried suggestions like [uncommenting the listener setting in server.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378701/9754418), but that didn't change anything.

Installing `kcat` for troubleshooting didn't work for me, since there's no out-of-the box installation for the yum package manager, which Amazon Linux 2 uses, and since [these instructions](https://fmunz.medium.com/kafkacat-on-amazonlinux-centos-d7ded88042e8) failed for me at `checking for libcurl (by compile)... failed (fail)`.

**The Question**: Any other tips on solving this "node assignment" error?

Comment: I have a feeling you'd get a more direct answer from MSK support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The created properties file is not automatically used; your command needs to include `--command-config client.properties`, where this properties file is documented at the MSK docs on the [linked IAM page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html).

Extract...

```
ssl.truststore.location=<PATH_TO_TRUST_STORE_FILE>
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

Alternatively, if the plaintext port didn't work, then you have other networking issues

Beyond these steps, I suggest reaching out to MSK support, and telling them to [update the "Create a Topic" page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-topic.html) to no longer use Zookeeper, keeping in mind that [Kafka 3.0 is not (yet) supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/supported-kafka-versions.html)

Comment: The flag was indeed needed, and so were the additional properties you listed, such as `ssl.truststore.location`, which with MSK requires creating a $400/month private CA with AWS Certificate Manager. It turns out, the serverless MSK cluster option (in preview since December 2021), only supports IAM authentication, so that's why the plaintext port 9092 wasn't working. As soon as I created a dedicated MSK cluster with everything else being the same, the topic creation command worked on the plaintext port.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation has been updated recently, I was able to follow it end to end without any issue (The IAM policy is now correct)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @OneCricketeer and the [AWS IAM Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html) said.
I used these properties as part of the Java code instead of passing them from command line.

Here is the code I used to create/delete kafka topics using IAM credentials

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapBrokers);
properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "AWS_MSK_IAM");
properties.put("sasl.jaas.config", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;");
properties.put("sasl.client.callback.handler.class", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties); // This creates the admin client 

adminClient.createTopics(topics); // This creates the topics
```

Make sure your IAM role has the right permissions as mentioned in the [AWS IAM Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html)

Comment: Btw, you can load a file using Properties class functions.